# Quorum Consensus - BAR (Byzantine Altruistic Rational) Fault Tolerance / BAR Fault Tolerance / BAR Model

Tags: security, consensus, quorum

I refer to http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~dahlin/projects/bft/
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/lorenzo/papers/sosp05.pdf
http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~fabianb/classes/cs-443-w07/BAR.pdf https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/09/02/software-bounded-rationality/

Does consensus mechanism (e.g., IBFT, Raft or Proof of Work, Proof of Stake, Casper FFG) within Ethereum/Quorum adopt or adhere to the BAR (Byzantine Altruistic Rational) Fault Tolerance / BAR Fault Tolerance / BAR Model?

What is the specified relationship between the consensus algorithms available in Ethereum/Quorum and BAR (Byzantine Altruistic Rational) Fault Tolerance Model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From my brief examination of the cited papers I can surmise that neither Raft implementation nor IBFT would fit BAR definitions.